# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

this error is coming:
connected to database
(node:159696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"
at model.Query.exec (/home/unknown_user/Web_Dev_Work/mongose server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4803:21)
at model.Query.Query.then (/home/unknown_user/Web_Dev_Work/mongose server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4902:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:159696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:159696) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const Product = require("./models/shopAppModel");

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "./views"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.json());


const connectdB = async function () {
  await mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shopApp")
    .then(() => {
      console.log("connected to database");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
connectdB();

app.listen(3000,()=>console.log("Hello"));
app.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
  const data = await Product.find({});
  res.render('data/showData' , {data})
});

app.get('/products/:id' , async (req , res)=>{
  const {id} = req.params;
  const product = await Product.findById(id);
  res.render('data/detail' , {product});
});

app.get('/products/new' ,(req , res)=>{
  res.render('data/new');
});
```

this is my shopAppMode:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const shopAppScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "We need a name here!"]
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        min:[0,"fill a valid Price!"]
    },
    category:{
        type:String,
        enum:["fruit" , "vegetable", "stationary","dairy"]
    }

})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product',shopAppScheme);
module.exports =  Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order of your route declarations:

```
app.get('/products/new', …)
app.get('/products/:id', …)
```

Express doesn't perform a *best* match, but a *first* match. And a request to `GET /products/new` is matching your `/products/:id` route, hence the error:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string)
```